# Snowflake: view definition too large (view definition are limited to 100kb)

Tags: view, definition, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to create a view on table having variant column.Each variant row having almost 13000 keys.I have such 397 rows in my table.I am dynamically generating a view definition from python to create a view that will have each key from variant row as column in view.But getting this error : view definition too large (view definition are limited to 100kb).

eg:

```
variant_column_data = {"a":1,"b":1},{"a":2,"b":2}
```

I want my view as

```
a b
1 1
2 2
```

I am able to create it with 6000 columns but getting this error for large view definition.Anyone can help me with solution or alternative solution for this?

Comment: So the final view should have 13000 columns? I think you might need to find a more suitable way to represent your data - what queries the view? Why do you need to have so many columns in your final view?

Comment: That is alot of columns. SimonD makes a good point via documentation: "The larger the number of materialized views on a shared base table, the more important it is to update that base table efficiently to minimize the costs of maintaining materialized views. https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/views-materialized.html "